# React on Kubernetes Ingress

Tags: reactjs, kubernetes, azure-aks

I deployed an application in Azure Kubernetes. I was trying to access the application through the Ingress Nginx controller. The Ingress is pointing to xxx.xxx.com and the app is deployed in the path "/react". So when I accessed the application I am able to see the title but I see the following the console
GET https://dns/static/css/main.c0f79ebd.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404. I was able to access the CSS files when I accessed it through https://dns/react/static/css/main.c0f79ebd.css. So how can I add /react to the generated files path?

Following is the dockerfile content

```
# build environment
FROM node:12.2.0-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package.json /app/package.json
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.0.1 -g --silent
COPY . /app
RUN npm run build

# production environment
FROM nginx:1.16.0-alpine
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Ingress Deployment

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  namespace: sample-ns
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - dns
    secretName: tls
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: my-react-app
          servicePort: 80
        path: /react(/|$)(.*)
```

Comment: This should help you [How to setup ingress to serve static content on kubernetes?](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/issues/323#issuecomment-453565034)

Comment: Still the same issue.

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputpublicpath  changing to /react?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "So how can I add /react to the generated files path?"?

Answer (score -1):

If you're using Create React App, you might need to update the 'homepage' setting to reflect that the files will be served from a subdirectory rather the site root.

Putting `"homepage": "https://dns/react"` in your package.json and rebuilding react/docker
and redeploying might do the trick.